# Unable to rename and delete file in Java

Tags: java, netbeans

I am doing a project in Java using NetBeans and I need to modify a file. So I overwrite the whole file in another temporary file, but at the end I could not rename the temporary file or delete the main file. Any solutions?

```
File tf = new File("F:\\nb\\project_inventory\\temp.tmp");

FileReader fr = new FileReader("F:\\nb\\project_inventory\\Employee_info.txt");
BufferedReader br =new BufferedReader(fr);

FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(tf);
PrintWriter bw =new PrintWriter(fw);
String line;
while((line=br.readLine())!=null)
{
    if(line.contains(del_id)) continue;

    bw.println(line);
}

bw.close();
fw.close();
br.close();
fr.close();
File real =new File("F:\\nb\\project_inventory\\Employee_info.txt");
real.delete();
tf.renameTo(real);
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting..

Comment: Why are you passing your fileWriter into your printWriter? `PrintWriter bw =new PrintWriter(fw);`

Comment: so what should i pass?

Answer (score 1):

I just tried 5 of the above project lines as below and got the desired result,

```
    File real =new File("F:\\nb\\project_inventory\\Employee_info.txt");
    real.delete();

    File tf = new File("F:\\nb\\project_inventory\\temp.tmp");
    try{
       tf.createNewFile(); // for creating the new file
       }
    catch(IOException e){
       e.printstacktrace();
       }
    File real =new File("F:\\nb\\project_inventory\\Employee_info.txt");
    tf.renameTo(real);
```

Employee_info.txt is getting deleted as well as temp.tmp is getting renamed as Employee_info.txt too.

Also, it is always recommended to put the code for delete/rename inside try/catch block like below:

```
 try{
        File real =new File("F:\\nb\\project_inventory\\Employee_info.txt");
        real.delete();
    }
    catch(IOException e){
        e.printstacktrace();
    }
```

Please provide the error message, to help you further.

Comment: @Stefan Dollase  Changed the catch block. My only intention was to talk about try & catch. But anyway, thanks for pointing out. :)

Comment: it is creating the temporary file with my desired content but neither deleting the real file nor renaming the temp file...

Comment: Can u try by commenting out all the lines other than the code for delete and rename and check once whether it is working fine.
Then we can scrutiny the rest of the code.

Comment: I tried to run commenting everything except rename and delete portion..no temporary file is created

Comment: for creating the new file , please use tf.createNewFile(); 
Modified the answer accordingly.

If it works, please accept the answer and vote it  up :)

Comment: temp file is created .. but real file is not deleted and temp is not renaming to it... i have tried same code in other project..it worked..but only in this case it is not working.. :(

Comment: please update ur code snippet..  i guess u have added the createNewFile() also..  It will be easier to find the problem then.

Comment: @Real Sazzad If the answer help you to resolve your problem, please upvote it and do accept the answer for future users.